# Reindexing elastic search index which have parent-child types

Tags: elasticsearch

**Description of problem :**
I have a index(sourceIndex) which have two types(Type A & Type B), Type A is a child type and Type B is parent of Type A , i happened to update analyzers for documents in sourceIndex so i created "destinatedIndex" with new analyzers and now i want to move documents to destinationIndex , biut when i use 'ReIndex' Api i am getting below error ,

---

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

---

How do i proceed to reindex documents from one index to another when when the source index ahve parent child relation types , also please let me know if i miss anything.

Thanks,
K

Comment: Can you show the reindex command you're running?

Comment: POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "suppliersproducts"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "relevancysearchtest"
  }
}

suppliersproducts is the source index with products(child) and supplierr(parent) types & 'relevancysearchtest' is the new index with new analyzers

Comment: How about reindexing the parent documents first (i.e. type supplier) and then in a second query the child documents (i.e. type products)?

Comment: haven't tried that way will give a try , also for some fields in the new type i want to apply newly configured analyzer , so that newly indexed fields for new type will take new index analyzers, how to achieve that ,would be helpful if you suggest a way.

Comment: @Val reindexed parent type first & it happened successfully but when tried reindexed child type then i am getting below error 

{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"
   },
   "status": 400
}

Comment: You also need to use a script and properly set the `_parent` field for each child document. Refer to the docs to see how to do this.

Comment: @Val i was able to use "reindex" and achieve my requirement , and thanks for your quick support.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to re-index in the above mentioned scenarios.

I created destination index with analyzers and parent child mappings(created parent and child types at a time) , and then used reindex query to reindex from source to destination(new index) indices.Doing so i was able to eliminate parent-child relation complexities.

Thanks,
K.